# Run SQL Query with COUNT(*) so we know how many records would come through DataReader

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ado.net

I have the following query that I use to pull data out of a mysql database.

```sql
SELECT ProductCode, ProductName, ProductCategory
   FROM Product
      WHERE <<Criteria goes here>>
```

The data returned by the query is consumed by the .NET Application and I am getting a million rows which I am going through one by one through the DataReader.

Now I have to show the progress bar telling users how many percentage of rows have been received. Which means I need a total number

A friend suggested me to add COUNT(*) as an extra column, which will have the repeated number but we don't have to do two round-trips one to get count and other to get the rows.

```sql
SELECT ProductCode, ProductName, ProductCategory, COUNT(*)
   FROM Product
      WHERE <<Criteria goes here>>
```

mysql is giving back only one record when I add COUNT(*). 
And 2nd, I am not sure if this is a good idea.

Please share what you know about this Thanks

Comment: SQL Server `OUTPUT` parameter values aren't available until after the `DataReader` is closed. ([Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx).) A stored procedure can return multiple recordsets, e.g. one with the count and another with the data, but that may not help here. When the number of rows being returned is smaller it may make sense to cache them in a temporary table or table variable in order to return the count first. Is it possible to perform a fast `Count()` that will provide a value sufficiently accurate for displaying % complete?

Comment: I am using mysql not SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

e.g.
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, ProductCode, ProductName, ProductCategory
   FROM Product
      WHERE <>

and then run this query to get number of rows without filtering
'select FOUND_ROWS();'

Comment: Interesting. I have to find a way to fit this into the MySqlDataReader. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: I tried to fit this into output parameter, but parameter value is coming back null. Apparently the guy who said something about output parameters not set until datareader is closed was right.

Answer (score 1):

A DBMS might start returning rows to the client before the answer set is fully created, then the only way to get a 100% correct value is to run the select with a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your query) x;
```

before you run the query or to use count as a window function, but this is not supported by MySQL:

```
SELECT ProductCode, ProductName, ProductCategory, COUNT(*) OVER () 
   FROM Product
      WHERE <<Criteria goes here>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are loading the retrieved records in a `DataTable`, just check the `DataTable.Rows.Count()` property to see how many you have.

Comment: I am using DataReader.

Comment: @fahadash: Throw the results from your query into a datatable and work off of that.

Comment: Wont that be an overhead ? Because in order to build datatable I have to go through all the reader's records and if I am going through reader I might as well just process those records as I receive them right ?

Comment: @fahadash: By the time the `DataReader` allows you to iterate through the records the command object has already executed and the server has returned the results.  There is no more "overhead" to worry about.

Comment: But the question is, by the time reader is ready; are all the rows downloaded to the client machine?

Comment: @fahadash: yes they are.